# The range of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2x}}$

Tags: functions

Find the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2x}}$.

By simply looking at the problem and simplifying trigonometrically,it looks as if range is zero but not.I think there is some trick to solve this.I am perplexed.I tried to find the domain first but not successful.Please help....

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\sin x\cdot|\cos x| - \cos x\cdot|\sin x|$

Comment: Use the fact that: $1+\tan^2{x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}$

Comment: Hint - Use trigonometric simplifications - the function is continuous with period $2\pi$. The simplifications will reveal the range easily (You can find maxima and minima)  - probably it is -1 to 1. Michael has already outlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle |\sin x|=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \sin x \;,& \displaystyle 0 \leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\\\ 
\displaystyle \sin x \;,& \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x\leq \pi \\\\ 
 \displaystyle -\sin x\;, & \displaystyle\pi \leq x\leq \frac{3\pi}{2} \\\\ 
 \displaystyle -\sin x \;,& \displaystyle\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq x\leq 2\pi
\end{matrix}\right.$ and $\displaystyle |\cos x|=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\displaystyle \cos x \;,& \displaystyle 0 \leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2} \\\\ 
\displaystyle -\cos x \;,& \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x\leq \pi \\\\ 
 \displaystyle -\cos x \;,& \displaystyle\pi \leq x\leq \frac{3\pi}{2} \\\\ 
 \displaystyle \cos x \;,& \displaystyle\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq x\leq 2\pi
\end{matrix}\right.$

So $$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}-\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2x}} = \sin x\cdot \left|\cos x\right|-\cos x\cdot \left|\sin x\right|$$

Here Function $f(x)$ is Periodic With Time Period $= 2\pi.$

So we will Calculate for Only one Time Period.

In $\bullet \displaystyle \; 0 \leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\;,$ We get $f(x) = \sin  x\cdot \cos x-\cos x\cdot \sin x = 0$

In $\bullet \displaystyle \; \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x\leq \pi\;,$ We get $f(x)=-\sin 2x .$ So $0 \leq f(x)\leq 1$

In $\bullet \displaystyle \; \pi \leq x\leq \frac{3\pi}{2}\;,$ We get $f(x)=0 .$

In $\bullet \displaystyle \; \frac{3\pi}{2} \leq x\leq 2\pi\;,$ We get $f(x)=\sin 2x .$ So $-1 \leq f(x)\leq 0$

So Here We get $\displaystyle -1 \leq f(x)\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

The function is indeed zero in $[0,\pi/2]$, but is not zero in $[\pi/2, \pi]$. This is because $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$, but rather $|x|$.

Thus, in areas where both $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are jointly positive or negative, the function will be zero. But in cases where they are not...

Comment: Is it answer?..

Comment: @MichaelGaluza - more of a hint.

Comment: @nbubis,in the first and third quadrant,answer is zero and in the second and fourth quadrant,answer is $2 \sin x \cos x$ and $-2 \sin x \cos x$ resp,but what should be the final answer.

Comment: @Brahmagupta, where will those functions obtain maximal values? Also, downvoting is not very nice.

Comment: @nbubis,sir i have not downvoted you.

Comment: @nbubis,maybe someone else has done.

Comment: @Brahmagupta - note that $2\sin x \cos x= \sin 2x$, which range $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score -2):

if sinx>=0 and cosx>=0 : f(x)=0
if sinx>=0 and cosx<=0 (90<=x<=180) : f(x)=-2sinx.cosx=-sin(2x)

180<=2x<=360 :   -1<=sin(2x)<=0  :     0<=-sin(2x)<=1   :   0<=f(x)<=1

if sinx<0 and cosx<0 : f(x)=0

if sinx<=0 and cosx>=0 : (-90<=x<=0) : f(x)=2sinx.cosx=sin(2x)

-180<=2x<=0 :  -1<=sin2x<=0 :   -1<=f(x)<=0

So -1<=f(x)<=1

Comment: Maybe you should to use latex? Anyway, your answer is wrong.

Comment: Because $-1\le f(x)\le 1$. You can see [picture](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29*abs%28cos%28x%29%29+-+cos%28x%29*abs%28sin%28x%29%29+from+x%3D-pi+to+pi). Or, you said $f(x)=\sin(2x)$.